# ScriptLab in Excel 2019 keeps crashing and restarting on loading

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

In Excel 2019, ScriptLab crashes as soon as it should load. If I click Code, Run or Functions in the ScriptLab-Tab, ScriptLab opens a window, tries to load apparently, the screen turns white and ScriptLab tries to load again until it fails and everything repeats. This leads to an infite loop where it keeps restarting to load and I never get beyond that loading screen.

ScriptLab used to work for me but it appears that after trying to switch between newer and older version, somewhere it got malconfigured and now i cannot start it anymore. Reinstalling didn't work for me either.

Comment: I just tried on my Excel version 2006(Build 13001), it works expected. I also tried on Excel Online and Mac (version 16.38), it works as well. could you please try the same gist on Excel online?

Comment: I don't use any gists. Just pure empty ScriptLab with nothing else.

Comment: Are you observing this issue recently? what do you mean by swtiching between newer and older version?

Comment: I observe this issue in this very moment and can not do anything about it. With switching versions i mean: While having a ScriptLab-Code Window open, you can press the cogwheel in the lower right corner and than you can switch in the lower left corner from "Production" to Beta, Alpha and 2017. This is what i played around with in my local Excel-installation

Comment: You can see here what it looks like: https://www.screenpresso.com/=9mHJc

Comment: Do you want to try Excel online and see if it works? meanwhile could you please try to reboot your machine and try it again?

Comment: The problem persists after restarting my machine. If i work with Excel Online it works just fine, but i need to get this to work inside my local installation